# How do I make a sibling expand item collapse as I'm opening other accordion items in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to develop a simple accordion from scratch, but this one issue is keeping me away from doing so.

I am trying to achieve an effect, where you can expand the item, content pops up, plus icon turns into a minus of the target accordion item - so far everything is done.

**The problem**:

If you have one accordion item opened and try to open another one, the content collapses as it should, but the minus icon of the previous accordion item isn't turning to a plus with the code below. I know it is missing something on the jQuery end, but I can't figure out what do I need to add.

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ygjbab2h/

Here is the code I have so far:

Jquery:

```
$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.slideToggle(0);
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
    $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.plus-minus-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 21px;
    position: relative;
    width: 21px;
}

.plus-minus-toggle:before,
.plus-minus-toggle:after {
    background: #000;
    content: '';
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 21px;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

.plus-minus-toggle:after {
    transform-origin: center;
}

.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:before {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the headings that aren't the current one something like:

```
$('.accordion-item .heading').not(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed')
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ygjbab2h/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Shame I can select only one solution, because all replies I have so far are working. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is simpler solution, but you can use this, too:

```
$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $content = $(this).next();
            $content.slideToggle(0);
            $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
            $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).prev().find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed');

          $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');

});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $content = $(this).next();
            $content.slideToggle(0);
            $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
            $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).prev().find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
  
          $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
           
});
```

```css
.plus-minus-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
height: 21px;
position: relative;
width: 21px;
}

.plus-minus-toggle:before,
.plus-minus-toggle:after {
    background: #000;
    content: '';
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 21px;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

.plus-minus-toggle:after {
    transform-origin: center;
}

.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:before {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="heading">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Heading
                <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content" style="display: none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $content = $(this).next();
        $content.slideToggle(0);
        $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
        $('.plus-minus-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');
        $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
```

});